# MySQL Triggers and Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, triggers

I have three tables as shown below:

[image]

I have written a MySQL trigger to call  a procedure to change the delivery channel of a mod whenever the delivery channel of a pac changes. There is a many to many relationship between the two an that is I have pac_mods table.

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER pac_delivery_channel_change_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON pacs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.delivery_channel <> OLD.delivery_channel THEN
      CALL updateMods(Old.id, New.delivery_channel);
    END IF;
END;    
$$
```

And the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateMods(IN pacID INT, IN newDeliveryChannelID INT) 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE mods md     
    INNER JOIN     
    pac_mods pmds ON pmds.mod_id = md.id     
        SET md.delivery_channel = newDeliveryChannelID  
        WHERE pmds.pac_id = pacID; 
END;
$$
```

There are no errors when I run the statements in mysql but it does not work.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: At my side all this staff works on MySQL 5.6 on Windows. Please check that the trigger has been created on pacs.

Comment: Thanks. It works OK. I had made a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works, I made a stupid mistake and only realized it after I had already posted the question.

The mistake was using the wrong fields in the if statement in the actual code that I ran in MySQL.

I hope this can help someone some day.

Thanks